# How to make listviews onitemclicklistener work?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I've been looking for the ways to make the my listview work. I used almost all the things I know and the things I saw here. I used code and XML tags but it still doesn't work. I've been changing where to put those blockdecendants, focusable, clickable tags in the xml.

here is my relevant code:

```
lstMeals = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstMeals);

lstMeals.setItemsCanFocus(true);
lstMeals.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

this is the xml with the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pgMeals"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMNoRecord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstMeals"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout>
```

this is the layout of the adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mealInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgMeal"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/picLayout"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgMeal"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtWatermark"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:text="Large Text"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtWatermark2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Large Text"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adptrMealName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black80"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMealDesc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtMealPrice"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black70"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnViewIngredients"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtMealDesc"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="View Ingredients"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMealPrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/adptrMealName"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black70"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout>
```

Comment: Write on click listener bottomsheet in your adapter class

Comment: why should i put an onclicklistener? the thing that is not working fine is the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a lot for the help. i already found the answer. the problem was caused by the **bottomsheet**. it was not used by the adapter because the activity is the one that shows the bottomsheet. this code is my friend's code that's why i don't know somethings about it.

Answer (score 0):

this may work.....

```
    clubList = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.club_listview_dialog);
    clubList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //postion is the position of item clicked in the list
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi AwaisMajeed, thanks for the help.i tried this but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your onCreate.

```
lstmeals.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position->" + position + "is selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks tahsinRupam, but it only allows the adapterview.onitemclicklistener

Comment: @RickyManalo, `ListView` extends `AdapterView`, so every `ListView` is an `AdapterView` as well.

Comment: Is this answer solved your problem? If it helped you can mark it as accepted, others can be helped by this in future.